# Convert time milis to date format using Time::Local

Tags: perl

Is it possible to convert timi milis since the epoch in Perl using `Time::Local` or another package that is included with the standard Perl distribution, i.e. which doesn't have to be added separately using a package manager like `ppm`?  The problem is, I work in a super-restricted network environment and the script I am writing doesn't warrant going through the red tape to get something external like `DateTime` or `Time::HiRes`.

E.g., I have milis like `1354996539` and I would like to format it to `2012-12-11 13:45:34`

Thanks

Comment: Not that it affects the answer to the question, but `Time::HiRes` is core too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time::Local's `timelocal` does the opposite of what you want (1354996539 is the output, not the input). The function after which it's named, [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html), is actually the one you want.

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );
say strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', localtime(1354996539));
```

Outputs (for someone in America/Toronto):

```
2012-12-08 14:55:39
```

You can also do it without `strftime`:

```
my @ts = localtime(1354996539);
$ts[4] += 1;
$ts[5] += 1900;
say sprintf('%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d', @ts[5,4,3,2,1,0]);
```